# Add test object in Test set in QC through OTAClient in JAVA

Tags: java, interface, hp-quality-center, com4j

I have a list of test ids which are to be added in a newly created test set.
For getting test details [or test objects] i am using the following code:

```
 ITestFactory sTestFactory = (QCConnection.testFactory()).queryInterface(ITestFactory.class);
ITest iTest = (sTestFactory.item(63514)).queryInterface(ITest.class);
```

I am also able to get the test set object by using the interface ITestSet.
Now I am stuck on how to add the test object in the test set.
Tried with the following code and its not even throwing any exceptions but still is not so useful:

```
IBaseFactory testFactory = testSet.tsTestFactory().queryInterface(IBaseFactory.class);
IList testInstances = testFactory.newList(null);
testInstances.add(iTest);
```

Can anyone provide a quick help?
Used JAVA - com4j with OTAClient jar.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am feeling stupid at the moment. The answer is very simple and sorry i wasted a space on the forum. But might be helpful to someone with similar requirement.
The code is as simple as :

```
IBaseFactory testFactory = testSet.tsTestFactory().queryInterface(IBaseFactory.class);
testFactory.addItem(iTest);
```

where iTest is the object from test plan

```
ITestFactory sTestFactory = (QCConnection.testFactory()).queryInterface(ITestFactory.class);
ITest iTest = (sTestFactory.item(63514)).queryInterface(ITest.class);
```

I am sorry again for wastage of time and space!